# How use OData filters with swagger in an asp.net core WebApi project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, odata, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an web API written using C# on the top of ASP.NET 5/core with EntityFrameworkCore.

I am using [OData](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData/) to apply filters on when querying the database.

I need to manually apply the `ODataQueryOptions` to my `DbSet<>` to generate paged info.

Here is my code

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ProductsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly DbContext _db;

    public ProductsController(DbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All, AllowedFunctions = AllowedFunctions.AllFunctions, MaxTop = 500)]
    public PagedProduct Search(ODataQueryOptions<Product> queryOptions)
    {
        // create a query for that would count the total rows
        var countQuery = queryOptions.ApplyTo(Repository.Query(),  AllowedQueryOptions.Top | AllowedQueryOptions.Skip) as IQueryable<Product>;

        // create a query to pull the data
        var query = queryOptions.ApplyTo(Repository.Query()) as IQueryable<Product>;

        var result = new PagedProduct()
        {
            CurrentPage = 1, // TODO get the current page value from the queryOptions
            PageSize = 100,  // TODO get the page size value from the queryOptions
        };

        result.TotalRecords = await countQuery.Count();
        result.Data = await query.ToList();

        return result;
    }
}
```

But the above code cause Swagger UI to fail. I get the following error

> Fetch error
> undefined /swagger/v1/swagger.json

That error is caused by using `ODataQueryOptions` as parameter into the Search action.

How can I get the Swagger UI to work with `ODataQueryOptions`?

Comment: Have you tried adding the Odata specific attributes to the route?
`[ODataRoute]`
`[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ODataValue<IEnumerable<Product>>), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]`

Comment: ODataValue does not exists in the package

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into similar problem few years ago, so maybe my solution will be useful to you.

I used "native" parameters instead of ODataQueryOptions in my controller:

```
    [Route("", Name = "GetDocuments")]
    [HttpGet]
    [Produces(typeof(PageDto<DocumentShortDto>))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetDocumentsAsync(
        [FromQuery(Name = "$top")] int top,
        [FromQuery(Name = "$skip")] int skip,
        [FromQuery(Name = "$orderby")] string orderby,
        [FromQuery(Name = "$filter")] string filter)
```

Then I created ODataQueryOptions with the help of the following class:

```
public static class ODataBuilder
{
    public static ODataQueryOptions<T> BuildOptions<T>(HttpRequest request)
    {
        var modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        modelBuilder.AddEntityType(typeof(T));
        var edmModel = modelBuilder.GetEdmModel();
        var oDataQueryContext = new ODataQueryContext(edmModel, typeof(T), new ODataPath());

        return new ODataQueryOptions<T>(oDataQueryContext, request);
    }
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that the user can now specify required parameters and run requests in Swagger.

If Swagger throws **InvalidOperationException** with the message "*Add at least one media type to the list of supported media types*", it means that some OData formatters have unsupported media types.

Since service uses only native parameters and doesn't respond with OData, you can safely remove all OData formatters at startup code and resolve this issue:

```
services.AddMvcCore(options =>
{
    var inputFormattersToRemove = options.InputFormatters.OfType<ODataInputFormatter>().ToList();
    foreach (var formatter in inputFormattersToRemove)
    {
        options.InputFormatters.Remove(formatter);
    }

    var outputFormattersToRemove = options.OutputFormatters.OfType<ODataOutputFormatter>().ToList();
    foreach (var formatter in outputFormattersToRemove)
    {
        options.OutputFormatters.Remove(formatter);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help here. I Tried that but getting this error `The query specified in the URI is not valid. The limit of '0' for Top query has been exceeded. The value from the incoming request is '500'` I decorated my action method with this `        [EnableQuery(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All, AllowedFunctions = AllowedFunctions.AllFunctions, MaxTop = 1000)]` so the max it can be is 1000 but I am requesting 500 yet it saying the limit is 0

Comment: Hmm.... This worked successfully with Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 7.4.0-beta.

Comment: EnableQueryAttribute is useless, I think. You should set MaxTop manually. Maybe reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options#ODataQueryOptions will be helpful.

Comment: Thank again! I am going to accept the answer. However, there is this issue now `The property 'Title' cannot be used in the $filter query option. I am guessing I need to configure a service somehow to allow odata to filter by all the properties. Any idea how? Here is how I currently configure odata `services.AddControllers().AddOData();`

Comment: Yes, you must configure Odata with call services.AddOData(). But I remembered that in addition to this, I needed to remove the OData formatters:

Comment: https://pastebin.com/9USs6gz3